# Why jQuery .val() work and js .value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with jQuery .val() method and native js .value. I have a function that I use in 2 different page, my html code is :

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkEntreeLun" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkEntreeMar" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkEntreeMer" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkEntreeJeu" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkEntreeVen" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkEntreeSam" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkEntreeDim" value=""/>
```

And for the other page this is the same code, except there is a default value in the inputs. And now in my js function, I need to get the value of each input. So here is what I have :

```
for (i=0;i<days.length;i++){
        var nameEntree = "checkEntree"+days[i];
        var checkEntreeMatin = $("input[name='"+nameEntree+"']").val();

     //Do something with value ...
}
```

Here comes the problem, for the page where there is no default value in the input, I can get the value with `document.getElementsByName("checkEntree"+days[i]).value` and not with .val() method and when I use .val() method I can get the value on the page where there is default value.

Why it's working with a method and not with the other and vice versa ?

Comment: [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) return a NodeList

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("checkEntree"+days[i])[0].value`, `getElementsByName` returns a live [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ok thanks, but what's the problem with the .val() method then ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `name` and not `id`?

Comment: @bukko because of the possible form ? names are used when submit the form

Comment: @Kacketo I would still use an id for selectors though

Answer (score 0):

`$(someSelector)` returns a jQuery object. `val()` is a method that appears on jQuery object that gets the first or sets the value of all the Elements that object contains (or does nothing if the selector didn't find any).

`getElementsByName` returns a [Node List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is an array-like object where each member is an HTML Element Node. It doesn't have a `value` property, although each HTML Element Node does.

In order to use `getElementsByName`, you need to access the individual Elements explicitly, e.g. by looping over the result.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("checkEntree"+days[i]);
for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    elements[j].value = ...;
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but I mean what's the problem with .val() method then ?

Comment: The problem you describe with the `val()` method appears to be "When there isn't a value, you don't get a value" … which doesn't really seem to be a problem. Maybe you need to construct [a better test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what result you expect and what result you get.

Comment: These inputs are filled by the user, so yes .val() should return me a value

Comment: @SimonM. — The inputs in your question are hidden, they can't be filled in by the user. You really do need to construct [a proper test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I use a function that fill these inputs thanks to other inputs, so this is not the problem

Comment: @SimonM. — You really do need to construct [a proper test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).